# Create a new column in MySQL into year and month string using a date column

Tags: mysql

I have the following column in MySQL table which is `YYYYMMDD`:

```
launch_month    
2018-06-01  
2018-07-01      
2018-08-01
```

I want to create a new column along side this using the string of `'201806'`, so using the above the new column would look like:

```
launch_id
201806  
201807  
201808
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string functions like `replace()` and `left()`:

```
select launch_month, 
       left(replace(launch_month, '-', ''), 6) launch_id
from tablename
```

Or [`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
select launch_month, 
       date_format(launch_month, '%Y%m') launch_id
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=511de35d4457970574f530516a8ad911).

Results:

```
| launch_month | month  |
| ------------ | ------ |
| 2018-06-01   | 201806 |
| 2018-07-01   | 201807 |
| 2018-08-01   | 201808 |
```

Comment: I like the `date_format`, but this is just selecting. He's asking to create a new column... see my answer.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' don't take *create a new colum* literally. In most cases it just means `select...` with a new column.

Comment: Sure, all depends on what you need. I find it better practice to parse as low as possible on the db layer. Better for data integrity, caching and mainly indexing.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) based on launch_month (date) and [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), as described by @forpas.

```sql
ALTER TABLE launches
  ADD launch_id INT AS (DATE_FORMAT(launch_month, '%Y%m')) STORED;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cdce9dc07e54a274685e513b781574b) :)

This format can be safely retyped to `INT`.

For selecting only, you can use `VIRTUAL` column (instead of `STORED`). Then your launch_id is calculated on every select, but doesn't store the data twice.

For indexing, you need the column to be `STORED`.