how to create 3 new columns day,month,year from existing date column in my sql
how to create 3 new columns day,month,year from existing date column in my sql
i tried ..but didnt get it using alter
this is a concept of feature engineering from data science.
can anyone provide solution query for this using MySQL.

Use the YEAR(), MONTH(), and DAY() functions.

Use generated columns rather than real columns, so you don't need to do anything to keep it consistent with the date column.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729021/create-a-new-column-in-mysql-into-year-and-month-string-using-a-date-column for examples of creating generated columns.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use generated columns to achieve that without duplicating the data.
Generated columns let you add new columns to your table that are derived from existing columns in your data. In this way you can add the day, month and year properties without duplicating any data (which would consume more disk space and risk data inconsistencies).
Assuming you have a column called date, the code to add the generated columns to the table would look something like this:
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD COLUMN day INT AS (DAY(date)),
  ADD COLUMN month INT AS (MONTH(date)),
  ADD COLUMN year INT AS (YEAR(date));

This will compute the day, month and year properties every time you query the table. You could also use the STORED keyword to compute these columns when data is inserted / updated and keep it on disk (uses up more space but could speed up queries):
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD COLUMN day INT AS (DAY(date)) STROED,
  ADD COLUMN month INT AS (MONTH(date)) STROED,
  ADD COLUMN year INT AS (YEAR(date)) STROED;

